# Get 5th function parameter with ARM GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb, arm, reverse-engineering

I have function that looks like following one:

```
MyFunction(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, char *arg5)
```

I have to get this function 5th parameter with GDB on machine code level (i. e. I don't have C++ source for this function, I just know its prototype for sure). How can I get 5th paramter with GDB? If I do following right before `BL MyFunction`:

```
(gdb) frame 0
```

It will give me `arg5` value, so I can pass this value to `x/s` to get NULL-terminated string passed as `arg5`, is that correct?

Comment: Did you try one of `info args`, `info locals` or `info frame`?

Comment: These commands doesn't work during reverse engeneering; they require symbols. `info arg` shows errors, `info locals` also, `info frame` shows information about `sp` and `pc`, but of course no names without symbols. I found solution, `frame 0` is wrong command, correct one is `x/x sp` for 5th argument. I found it by reading 5th argument where it is constant, so I could see whether I use correct address. `frame` tries to find return address on stack and not variable value.

Comment: The issue is that parameters are passed in register for parameters 1-4, but parameter 5 must be passed on the stack.  If you give `gdb` no debug info, then it can not know where on the stack the 5th parameter is located.  In order to get this information, you must *decompile* the assembler; Ie, something must analyze the assembler to know where on the stack frame the 5th arg is.

Comment: If question is just "It will give me arg5 value, so I can pass this value to x/s to get NULL-terminated string passed as arg5, is that correct?", that shouldn't be hard to experiment right?

Comment: The data wasn't readable; it was binary data, and experiment to check if binary data I received is correct was not easy. Data was the text encrypted with AES, so it is not possible to check whether random bytes from wrong stack location are ciphertext or something else.